# Hits counter in txt file count visitors when open page simultaneously

Tags: php, count, counter

I am using this to count the hits to my website:

```
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

$counterVal++;
$f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
fwrite($f, $counterVal);
fclose($f);
```

I want to ask you if there could be a problem when 2 or more visitors opens the page at the same time? If yes, how to make this to count all hits?

When (for example) 100 users opens the page at exactly same time, the file won't be locked by one of them?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem in that, if N visitors opens page at the same time then your counter in text file will increment by N.

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND thank you very much for your response. So, if all N visitors opens the txt file at the same time, and the txt file contains the number 5 (for example), the txt file opened by all N visitors contains 5 (right?). Why the final number won't be 6?

Comment: When N+1 user hits the page then it will be 6. Your counter starts form 0, right?

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND Right.

Comment: Ok, so when (for example) 100 users opens the page at exactly same time, the file won't be locked by one of them?

Comment: No, will not be a problem

Comment: You will need locking if you want to have consistent results with many concurrent hits. Otherwise, what happens when two or more sessions read the file at the same time -> the counter will be incremented with 1 only.

Comment: I use such code flock($f,2); fwrite($f, $thng); flock($f,3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
$filename = "counter.txt";
$number = file_get_contents($filename); 
$file = fopen($filename, 'a'); 
if (flock($file, LOCK_EX)) { 
    ftruncate($file, 0);
    fwrite($file, $number+1); 
    flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
} 
fclose($file);
```